# Binding DataGridViewColumn to 2nd level object

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I would like to bind a column in my DataGridView class to an entry in a 2nd level object in C# using .NET 4.0.  For instance:

I have Object A:

```
public class A
{
   public long id;
   public B bClass;
}
```

and Object B

```
public class B
{
   public long id;
   public string name;
}
```

Is there a way to declare a list of class A's as the data source on a DataGridView, yet bind one of the columns to the name attribute in Class B?

I distilled this down a little bit, but hopefully this isn't confusing.  Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
When you bind, you do this:

```
grid.DataSource = MyAList;
grid.DataMember = "bClass";
grid.DataBind();
```

Now when you're binding, you're evaluating to the members of class B.

Comment: But won't that bind incorrectly? My understanding is that data grid can only bind to primitives, collections/enumerables or INotifyPropertyChanged interfaces.

Comment: @AK; you can always handle specific binding in the `ItemDataBound` event.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution doesn't work for me. I understood the question more like in this thread: [Is it possible to bind complex type properties to a datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121274/is-it-possible-to-bind-complex-type-properties-to-a-datagrid)

What I did is to implement a class C in the gui-layer that has all the wanted properties in the first level. You can also write a constructor initializing the new class from class A:

```
public class C
{
    public C(A a)
    {
        Id = a.Id;
        Bid = a.bClass.Id;
        Bname = a.bClass.Name;
    }

    public long Id;
    public long Bid;
    public string Bname;
}
```