# How to bind virtual member to DataGridView in C# & Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

I have these classes for products and Units

```
public class Product
{
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int UnitId { get; set; }
        public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
}

public class Unit
{
        public int UnitId { get; set; }
        public string UnitName{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind a list of these entities to a `DataGridView` dynamically. And I did it successfully but I am facing problem in displaying the name of the unit.

I tried this code for that, but no luck!

```
var F1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
F1.HeaderText = "Unit";
F1.DataPropertyName = "Unit=>UnitName";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(F1);
```

and

```
var F1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
F1.HeaderText = "Unit";
F1.DataPropertyName = "Unit.UnitName";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(F1);
```

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121274/is-it-possible-to-bind-complex-type-properties-to-a-datagrid

Comment: do you get an error ?