# How to disable one ComboBox in a DataGridViewComboboxColumn where a nested property is presented?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I display list of objects in dataGridView. The list is like:

```
List<IAction> actions = new List<IAction>
```

I displayed nested property (not defined in the IAction interface) on DataGridViewComboBoxColumn() using **karlipoppins** answer here (reflection) [Is it possible to bind complex type properties to a datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121274/is-it-possible-to-bind-complex-type-properties-to-a-datagrid)

but I have a problem with making the combobox disabled  when where is no Area property in one kind of object

Hope you will help me ;)

On the list there are two types of objects:

```
public class MoveAction : IAction
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
     }

public class ClickAction : IAction
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
        public Area Area { get; set; }  //////////  Additional Property
    }
```

this additional property object looks like:

```
public class Area
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The dataGridView column is defined as follows:

```
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn CreateComboBoxWithArea()
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        combo.DataSource = areas.Select(t => t.Name).ToArray();
        combo.DataPropertyName = "Area.Name";
        combo.Name = "Area";
        return combo;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my own solution:

I have an access to the whole grid after casting the sender. After that I can do what I want with this one comboBox (hide the button, set readonly... ). That's because the fact the combobox has no property bool Enable ;/

Thanks for help jaredbaszler!

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)sender;
            DataGridViewRow row = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            DataGridViewColumn col = grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
            if (row.DataBoundItem != null && col.DataPropertyName.Contains("."))
            {
                string[] props = col.DataPropertyName.Split('.');
                PropertyInfo propInfo = row.DataBoundItem.GetType().GetProperty(props[0]);
                if(propInfo != null)
                {
                    object val = propInfo.GetValue(row.DataBoundItem, null);
                    for (int i = 1; i < props.Length; i++)
                    {
                        propInfo = val.GetType().GetProperty(props[i]);
                        val = propInfo.GetValue(val, null);
                    }
                    e.Value = val;
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
                    DataGridViewComboBoxCell chkCell = cell as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
                    chkCell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
                    cell.ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tie into the cell's `BeginEdit` event and cancel the editing of the combo at that point.  Like:

```
dataGrid.CellBeginEdit += dataGrid_CellBeginEdit;

void dgSamples_CellBeginEdit(object sender, GridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    var areaObject = e.Row.Cells["Area"].Value AS Area; // .Value will be the current selected item in the cell's combo.
    if (areaObject.Area == null)
    {
         e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

This won't show the combo as 'disabled' but it will prevent the user from dropping down the combo and changing the value.  Essentially make the cell read only.

Lastly, I'm not positive what type your `areas` list object is when you define the data source for the combo box. So I'm guessing at the type when I cast the `.Value` property to `Areas`.  You may need to change that.