# How can I see a specific object's attribute on a DataGridView's cell?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to be as clear as possible with this:

I have this class called "Tipo de Gasto"

```
public class CTipoGasto
{
    public static List<CTipoGasto> listaTipoGasto = new List<CTipoGasto>();
    public string descripción { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

}
```

And as it is shown below, this object is an attribute of another object called "Gasto"

```
public class CGasto
{
    public static List<CGasto> listaGasto = new List<CGasto>();
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public CTipoGasto tipoDeGasto { get; set; } //here
    public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
    public double precio { get; set; }
}
```

Each one of those two lists are Data Sources of two different "Data Grid View", but the Gasto's attribute `public CTipoGasto tipoDeGasto { get; set; }` is shown like this on Gasto's DGV:
[image: Click here to see the image]

So I wanted to know how do I have to do to show TipodeGasto's attribute "Descripción"

Answer (score 0):

Override the ToString function of your class:

```
public class CTipoGasto
{
  public static List<CTipoGasto> listaTipoGasto = new List<CTipoGasto>();
  public string descripción { get; set; }
  public int ID { get; set; }

  public override string ToString() {
    return descripción;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks! But.. is the "ID" Attribute hidden or something after that?

Comment: @juanzitelli To combine two properties, try `return ID.ToString() + ' ' + descripción;`

Comment: That sounds great, but what I actually meant was: How can I show "TipoGasto" 's ID Property as another column in the datagridview just as with "descripción"

Comment: @juanzitelli Depends.  How are you filling the DataGridView?  Using the DataSource?  Or adding rows manually?

Comment: Data Source!       `dgvGrillaGasto.DataSource = null;
            dgvGrillaGasto.DataSource = CGasto.listaGasto;
            List<CGasto> listaFiltrada2 = new List<CGasto>();
            if (txtBuscar.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                listaFiltrada2 = listaFiltrada2.FindAll(x => x.descripcion.ToUpper().Contains(txtBuscar.Text.ToUpper()));
            }
            dgvGrillaGasto.DataSource = listaFiltrada2;`

Comment: @juanzitelli See [Is it possible to bind complex type properties to a datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121274/719186)